# de Rham cohomology and connected components

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I'm trying to work out what $H^0_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{p,q\})$ is, and I've come across the fact that the dimension of $H^0_{dR}(M)$ is equal to the number of connected components of the manifold $M$. Is this true in general?

Is there a simple way to work out the number of connected components of, say, $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$? If so, how does one go about it?

Comment: That space is always (path) connected:  just travel around the finite number of obstructions.

Comment: So only 1 connected component then. Would this imply that $H^0_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{p,q\}) = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this fact is true in general and can be worked out by hand without referring to other cohomology theories: The key observation is that any *closed* function is necessarily locally constant, which you can show by passing to local coordinates. Using this, one can easily form a basis for the zero'th homology.